# Como ocultar Propriedades no DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

Como posso ocultar minhas propriedades a partir da minha classe base.
Quero ocultar as propriedades no ato de carregamento do DataGridView a partir da classe pessoa, talvez com uma sintaxe semelhante ao `[DisplayName("Titulo")]` minha intenção é controlar o que será exibido ao usuário a partir da minha classe e não ocultando as colunas no DataGridView manualmente!

```
public class Pessoa
{
   //Aqui eu quero usar uma sintaxe semelhante ao DisplayName para inativar essa properiedade la no meu DataGridView
   //Ex: [PropertyShow(false)]        
   public int id { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Nome da Pessoa")]
   public string nome { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoas : List<Pessoa>{}

public partial class CarregaGrid
{
   void Carrega()
  {
      Pessoas colecao =  new Pessoas();
      colecao.Add(new Pessoa(){id =1, nome = "Pessoa 1"});
      colecao.Add(new Pessoa(){id =2, nome = "Pessoa 2"});
      colecao.Add(new Pessoa(){id =3, nome = "Pessoa 3"});

      //Carregando o grid
      var grid  =  new DataGridView();
      grid.DataSource = colecao;

      //Ocultando a coluna manualmente
      //Nesse ponto que quero evitar ocultar as colunas no meu View quero controlar isso na minha Classe Pessoa
      grid.Columns["id"].Visible=false;

      }
}
```

Comment: apenas um teste: tenta com `[Browsable(false)]`, em um propertyGrid funciona, talvez no datagrid tambem

Comment: Funcionou amigo.
Utilizando o Browsable consigo consigo controlar minhas exibições.
Obrigado

Comment: @Rovann Linhalis funcionou para o DataGridView porém, parou de funcionar meus combobox que utilizam os ids das minhas classes, teria alguma outra dica?

Comment: cria um `modelView`, que basicamente é outra classe apenas para exibir os dados... aí você consegue ficar controlando essas particularidades... pra facilicar a "copia" dos dados entre essas classes, tem uma ferramenta, `automapper` que pode ser útil

Comment: Não entendi muit bem, teria um fragmento de código?

Comment: minha aplicação é Descktop por isso não compreendi direto a metodologia em Asp.net

Comment: é só a ideia do modelview, mas poderia aplicar também no winforms ou wpf. um exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ODPz4L e para facilitar a "cópia" de um objeto para outro, poderia usar o automapper... ou fazer a cópia manualmente